# How is this Promise working in javascript

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
Promise
.resolve()
.then(() => console.log(1))
.then(() => console.log(2))
.then(() => console.log(3));

Promise
.resolve()
.then(() => console.log(4))
.then(() => console.log(5))
.then(() => console.log(6));
```

Answer: `1 4 2 5 3 6`

May someone explain me how is it working?

Why it doesnt execute `1,2,3,4,5,6` ?

Comment: each promise chain is independent of the other - that's asynchrony - there's a more complex answer, involving event queues and microtask queue, but the point is that asynchronous code is not waited for unless you specifically code it that way (put that code in an async function, and await the first promise and you'll get exactly what you expect)

Comment: yeah right but why first run log(1) after that log(4) why not log(2)??

Comment: because first `Promise.resolve()` runs, then second `Promise.resolve()` runs, and only after that, each asynchronously called .then runs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.then` callback runs in a microtask, which only run once currently running synchronous code is complete. Here, the synchronous code initializes two Promises which resolve immediately, with `Promise.resolve`.

Microtasks resolve in order, so at the end of the script, there are two microtasks in the queue: the first one which was put onto the queue was `() => console.log(1)`, so that gets logged first. At this point, `1`'s Promise resolved, so the next `.then` (`2`) was put onto the microtask queue. The second one which was put onto the queue was `() => console.log(4)`, so that gets logged second, and `5` gets put onto the microtask queue. Then `2` runs and pushes its next `.then` onto the queue (3), then `4` runs and pushes its next `.then` (`6`) onto the queue. Etc.

```
// queue:
[1, 4]
// 1 gets logged
// 2 gets pushed
[4, 2]
// 4 gets logged
// 5 gets pushed
[2, 5]
// 2 gets logged
// 3 gets pushed
[5, 3]
...
```

If you had waited for the first Promise's whole Promise chain to fully resolve before continuing onto the second `Promise.resolve`, they'd all run in order, as you're expecting:

```js
(async () => {
  await Promise
  .resolve()
  .then(() => console.log(1))
  .then(() => console.log(2))
  .then(() => console.log(3));

  await Promise
  .resolve()
  .then(() => console.log(4))
  .then(() => console.log(5))
  .then(() => console.log(6));
})();
```

The above occurs because the Promise constructed by the `.resolve().then( ...)` Promise chain will only resolve once the *final* Promise in the chain resolves - that is, after `3` gets logged.

Comment: succinct and understandable explanation - the async/await code may be a little confusing to a newbie though :p

Comment: I think async/await should be actually more clear for a newbie than .then().